# piping qrencode to eog to avoid creating a file

Tags: shell, command

The following line in the terminal will save a .png image file for a weblink:

```
qrencode -o qrcode.png 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
```

You can then view the qrcode with

```
eog qrcode.png
```

How can you pipe the first command into the second and avoid creating a file?

Have tried for example:

```
qrencode 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page' | eog
```

..but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need an image viewer that is happy to read an image from a pipe. Here are two that will work.

Firstly, with `feh`:

```
qrencode -o - 'www.thesetchells.com' | feh -
```

Secondly, with **ImageMagick**:

```
qrencode -o - 'www.thesetchells.com' | magick display -
```

If you use older v6 **ImageMagick**, omit the word `magick` in the example above.

Comment: Thanks, both those commands work, tested them. I had a feeling after @Inian had all kinds of ideas that there was either something specific about qrencode or eog which was making it impossible - so there you have it, eog will not read from a pipe. Had to install feh, had never heard of it. It does not close with CTRL-W or CTRL-Q like eog, but seems to do something similar, just the sizing of the images is a bit different.

Comment: I saw you were struggling and that's why I was trying to help (actually by suggesting `feh`) in the comments on @Inian's answer, but I was away from a machine I could test on all weekend. Glad you've got it working now! You can pre-set the window geometry and use the zoom option with `feh`'s command-line, btw.

Answer (score 2):

### How to best create QR Codes in Linux, including Ubuntu:

### Summary

Do this:

First, install tools:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qrencode feh eog
```

Then:

1. Option 1 (now recommended, especially for Ubuntu 22.04 or later): pipe to the `feh` image viewer instead of to `eog`.

   *Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, 22.04.*

   ```bash
   # 1. 1-line cmd to make a QR code from a URL or text string
   qrencode -m 4 -o - "www.google.com" | feh -

   # 2. 1-line cmd to make a QR code from an entire file
   cat "path/to/file.txt" | qrencode -m 4 -o - | feh -
   ```

   - `qrencode -o -` says to write the output to stdout.
   - `feh -` says to read the input from stdin.
2. Option 2 (doesn't work well on Ubuntu 22.04): store in a temporary file, open in `eog`, then auto-remove the temporary file a moment later.

   *Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, and 22.04, but does *not* work well on 22.04 since the `eog` image viewer now auto-closes once the temporary file is removed!* In older versions of Ubuntu, the image viewer would stay open as-desired even after removing the temporary file.

   ```bash
   # 1. 1-line cmd to make a QR code from a URL
   qrencode -m 4 -o /tmp/qr.png "www.google.com" \
   && ((eog /tmp/qr.png &); sleep 1; rm /tmp/qr.png)

   # 2. 1-line cmd to make a QR code from an entire file
   cat "path/to/file.txt" | qrencode -m 4 -o /tmp/qr.png \
   && ((eog /tmp/qr.png &); sleep 1; rm /tmp/qr.png)
   ```

### More details

I want to point out that there's no real advantage to [using `feh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521674/4561887), so I recommend using `eog` with temporary files you manually make. `feh` is a primitive image viewer with no ability to zoom in and out that I can see. Additionally, *it uses temporary files anyway, so you're still creating temporary files by using it*. If you do this you'll see that:

```bash
qrencode -o - 'www.google.com' | feh -
```

Here is the output. I've highlighted the temporary file path in the image. In this case, it is `/tmp/feh_stdin_8WKtoo`:

[image]

You can even open this image in `eog` now!:

```bash
eog /tmp/feh_stdin_8WKtoo
```

[image]

And `eog` is a *much better* viewer, with zoom controls. You can zoom in and out with your mouse wheel.

#### Use `eog`

So, **you might as well just create *your own* temporary file and use `eog` to begin with, like this:**

```bash
qrencode -o /tmp/qr.png "www.google.com" && ((eog /tmp/qr.png &); sleep 1; \
rm /tmp/qr.png)
```

The `qrencode -o /tmp/qr.png` part stores the image into `/tmp/qr.png`. If that is successful (hence the `&&` part), `eog` opens that file in the background (`&`), then we wait a second to ensure `eog` has finished opening the file (`sleep 1;`), then we automatically remove it (`rm /tmp/qr.png`). Done.

[image]

#### Turn an entire text file into a QR code:

```bash
# Option 1: multiple lines

filename_to_encode="hello_world.sh"
cat "$filename_to_encode" | qrencode -m 4 -o "/tmp/qrcode.png"
# Use `&` to run in background so that the `rm` cmd next runs **immediately!**
eog "/tmp/qrcode.png" &
sleep 1
rm "/tmp/qrcode.png"

# Option 2: same thing as above, but in a 1-line script
cat "hello_world.sh" | qrencode -m 4 -o /tmp/qr.png \
&& ((eog /tmp/qr.png &); sleep 1; rm /tmp/qr.png)
```

Full-text QR codes like this <s>open best in apps like the Kaspersky QR Scanner</s> (see below).

#### Ensure `eog` doesn't blur your image when you zoom in

With `eog`open, click "Image Viewer" in the top-left of your main screen --> Preferences --> uncheck "Smooth images when zoomed out" and "Smooth images when zoomed in":

[image]

Now, you'll get nice, crisp edges for scanning the QR code with your phone. Make the "Image Viewer" full-screen, then zoom in, then easily scan it from your computer screen with your phone.

#### QR code reader app

For opening QR Codes, I recommend the [Kaspersky QR Scanner](https://usa.kaspersky.com/qr-scanner) for Android or iPhone. It has a couple features I really like:

1. It checks links for bad content before opening links.
2. If your QR code contains the contents of an entire file, it displays it nicely as a properly-formatted text file, according to the exact text in the QR code.

But, here's a HUGE con:

1. It seems to be limited to QR codes which contain < 1000 chars of text or so, so [I'm looking for something better](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82063/33099).

### References

1. [Ask Ubuntu: Zoom in on small photos without losing pixel crispness](https://askubuntu.com/q/237575/327339)

### See also:

1. Where I first learned about `qrencode`: https://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Generating-QR-Codes-in-Linux
2. [Software Recommendations: Secure QR code reader app for Android which can read very large QR codes (thousands of chars, ideally up to the max limit of 8000 chars or so)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/82063/33099)
3. [my answer] [Ask Ubuntu: Create QR code in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390582/327339)

<sub>Keywords: qr code generator in Linux</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-t utf8` option display the qr code directly in the terminal. Below is my personally favorite way to invoke this where I use `xclip` to pass the contents of my copy/paste clipboard into `qrencode` to generate the QR code.

```
  ~ xclip -o | qrencode -t utf8
█████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀ █ ▄█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ████
████ █   █ █▄ █▀▄█ █   █ ████
████ █▄▄▄█ █ ██▀ █ █▄▄▄█ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ ▀ ▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄████
████▄ █▄▀█▄▄▀  ███▄▄ █  ▀████
█████▄ ▀ ▀▄  █▄▀▄█ ▄▀ ██▄████
██████▄█▄█▄▄▀ █▀▄▀▀ ▄█▀▀ ████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▄▄▀▀▀▄▄▄▄█▄█████
████ █   █ █▀   █▄▄▀▀▀▀ ▀████
████ █▄▄▄█ █▀▀ █▄▀▀ ▄▄██▄████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄██▄▄██▄▄▄█▄█████
█████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████
```